# Use Sphinx doctest with docstrings that contain Matplotlib examples

Tags: python, matplotlib

The function shown below displays a line plot using Matplotlib. The docstring of the function contains an example of using the function with a list of numbers. I'm using the Sphinx `make html` command to create documentation for this function. I also use Sphinx to test the docstring using `make doctest`. However, doctest pauses when it tests this function because it displays a window containing the plot figure. I have to manually close the plot figure window for doctest to continue running. Is there a better way to use doctest with docstrings that contain Matplotlib examples?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_numbers(x):
    """
    Show a line plot of numbers.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : list
        Numbers to plot.

    Example
    -------
    >>> import calc
    >>> x = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8.1, 7, 10.5, 12]
    >>> calc.plot_numbers(x)
    """
    _, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, marker="o", mfc="red", mec="red")
    ax.set_xlabel("Label for x-axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Label for y-axis")
    ax.set_title("Title of the plot")

    plt.show()
```

Comment: I’m not sure, but you could try setting the backend to the non-interactive "agg" backend somewhere in your sphinx configuration https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/backends.html#selecting-a-backend

Comment: If it works, you will likely get warnings about `show` not working with "agg", which you might want to suppress somehow.

Comment: Don’t call plt.show?

Comment: @JodyKlymak If I don't call `plt.show` then how would I display the plot?

Comment: I’d let the user decide if they want to show the figure or not.  Also strongly suggest making figure and axes creation optional so folks can call your function with their own axes that may be part of a more complex layout.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Can you submit an answer with a code example of how you would write this function? I'm very interested in how you would implement the things mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would structure the plotting routine so the user could provide their own axes (and/or figure).  I wouldn't call `plt.show` for the user - how do you know they are ready to display the figure?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_numbers(x, *, ax=None):
    """
    Show a line plot of numbers.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : list
        Numbers to plot.
    ax: Axes
        Optional Matplotlib Axes to plot the numbers on.

    Example
    -------
    >>> import calc
    >>> x = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8.1, 7, 10.5, 12]
    >>> calc.plot_numbers(x)
    """
    if ax is None:
        _, ax = plt.subplots() 
    ax.plot(x, marker="o", mfc="red", mec="red")
    ax.set_xlabel("Label for x-axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Label for y-axis")
    ax.set_title("Title of the plot")

    return ax
```

See also https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/quick_start.html#making-a-helper-functions though note in that suggestion, `ax` is *required*.

Comment: This is definitely a better approach to write the function and thanks for sharing the link to the related Matplotlib docs. Do you have any comments on using doctest for the docstring in this function? Doctest will just check if the example in the docstring succeeds. Is there any way for doctest to actually check that the figure and/or axis object is correct?

Comment: I don't know how doctest works, but if you want to test your library, writing dedicated test suite and perhaps using https://github.com/matplotlib/pytest-mpl is the way to go.  You may want to look at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-extension-cookiecutter for how to create a package with a test suite and documentation.

Comment: Info about doctest is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html. It basically tests code written in docstrings. This is different than pytest which uses separate test functions to run unit tests. Anyway, thank you for the help.